# Rendering React Components to Specific Div Using Routing

Tags: meteor, reactjs, routes, flow-router

I am using FlowRouter as a router for a Meteor/React application I am trying to create. I'm having a very hard time trying to get my react components to render in specific places. Does anyone know how to do this?

So on my landing page, when I click a button, I want to route to a secondary page. I have three different components that I want to render in certain parts of the page. I've been using `ReactLayout.render()`, but I can't seem to make sure components get rendered in certain areas. I thought `document.getElementById` would work

```
ReactLayout.render(LandingPage, document.getElementById("landing-page")
```

but it hasn't been.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of ReactLayout.render expects an object.  If you want to render several components into your LandingPage element, it might look something like this:

```
LandingPage = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app-root">
        <AppHeader />
        <div className="container">
          {this.props.testOne}
        </div>
        <div className="app-root">
          {this.props.testTwo}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Then render using:

```
FlowRouter.route( '/testRedirect', {
  name: 'test',
  action() {
    ReactLayout.render( Default, { testOne: <TestOneComponent />, testTwo: <TestTwoComponent /> } );
  }
});
```